# Remove Recycle Bin from Desktop with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to remove the Recycle Bin icon from my Desktop using PowerShell in the latest Windows 11, and seem to be having issues with it.

[Many](https://www.lifewire.com/remove-recycle-bin-from-windows-desktop-5649317) [help guides](https://superuser.com/questions/1616394/how-to-use-registry-to-disable-recycle-bin-for-all-users-on-all-drives-and-disp) online seem to point towards the registry key `645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E` controlling the Recycle Bin; most suggest that simply deleting it with the command:

```
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}" -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

should work just fine.  However, I deleted the key and it's still on my desktop! I've tried logging in/out and restarting my computer, and the key is still gone but the Recycle Bin is still there, so it seems that this isn't the latest way to do this.

Given that this is pretty much where all posts I can find point to, I'm at a bit of a loss at how to proceed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: At least you could check if the key and the value in the registry are correct. Make a snapshot of your registry, remove the icon manually, make a snapshot again and compare both snapshots. ‍♂️

Comment: ... and maybe you have to restart the explorer to actually refresh the desktop after you deleted that key? ‍♂️

Comment: Shouldn't logging in/out and restarting the computer serve the same purpose of restarting explorer?  I've done both of those and no luck -- and the registry key is still gone! -- so it seems like the older solution isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to use Group Policies to achieve your goal.
You can manage Group Policies using Powershell but this will require to install and load the required Powershell Group Policy module(s).

The policy is located here:
[image]

That being said, you can, as a workaround, mimick the GPO setting by creating and setting the following key/value:

```
HKCR\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum
Create DWORD Key: {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Set Value to    : 1
```

Be aware that the Key **NonEnum** may not exist if no policies are applied.
Also the setting will only be effective for the current user.

Here is the Powershell code:

```
if((Test-Path -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum) -eq $false) {
    New-Item -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies -Name "NonEnum"
}
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum -Name "{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}" -Value 1 -Type DWord
```

**After that, you need to either kill and restart the Explorer.exe process or perform a reboot**.

Finally, you can also achieve your goal by creating and setting the following keys/values:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcon\NewStartPanel\
Create DWORD Key: {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Set Value to    : 1

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcon\ClassicStartMenu\
Create DWORD Key: {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Set Value to    : 1
```

But again, this will require to change the permissions of the registry key **ClassicStartMenu** because by default, Administrators only have read access. I won't recommend this method at all.

Everything described in this post has been tested on Windows 11. Hope this will help.